# "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" in a function

Tags: python

When I try to run a list through a function and get a new list returned, I get a "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" message for the 6th line. Both of the called variables, in the beginning, are lists if that helps.

The function is supposed to take the first and last digits of a list, add them, and then move on down the list towards the center. For example, the list [1, 4, 2, 2] would lead to a new list [3, 6]. This function only covers cases that are even, so no need to worry about that.

```
`def newListEven (l, newL):
    regular=l;
    reverse=l.reverse;
    newL=[];

    for n in range (0, int(len(l)/2)):
        variable=(regular(n)+ reverse(n));
        newL.append(variable);
    return newL;`
```

Anyways, as I mentioned earlier, I get a:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

message for the 6th line. However, it should transfer down to a print statement which would print the list.

Comment: What is `regular(n)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: `regular` is a list. To access its value use `regular[n]`.
Another thing 'reverse` is a function. Also read what `reverse` does (it will reverse array in place). You forgot parentheses i think. `()` are important.

Comment: l.reverse returns the *method*, it doesn't actually reverse the list. note  that `<list>.reverse()` reverses it inplace and returns `None`. also, probably going to run in to some other identity based problems...

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: There is no `;` in Python... Check it. Describe to us the logic of your code...

Comment: @codrelphi There is `;` in python.

Comment: You can do this in single line with list comprehension: `new.extend((l[n], l[-(n+1)]) for n in range(0, len(l), 2))`.

Answer (score 0):

- there are couple of issue with code.

  - `regular=l`. Here `l` is a list so does `regular`. To access list you need to use `[]`. Ex. `regular[0]`
  - second issue is with your `reverse=l.reverse`.

    - `l.reverse` is a method. Its a method that returns nothing. doing `l.reverse()` will revese the list `l`.
    - there is another bug with your code even after you make this two corrections. `<list>` are mutable. Consider following case.

```py
l = [1,2,3]
x = l
l.reverse()
print(l) # [3,2,1]
print(x) # [3,2,1]
```

- As in above case `l.reverse` will reverse both `l` and `x` since `x` is just reference to l. To avoid this use `copy` or just do `x=l[:]`.
- your code updated.

```py
def newListEven (l, newL):
    regular=l[:];
    l.reverse();
    newL=[];

    for n in range (0, int(len(l)/2)):
        variable=(regular[n]+ l[n]);
        newL.append(variable);
    return newL;
```

Comment: instead of copy, you can use `x = l[:]` (and to get it reversed: `reverse=l[::-1]`)

Comment: @Poojan: In `variable`, write `l[n]`instead of `reverse[n]`. Like `variable=(regular[n]+ l[n])`. Because `reverse`is not defined.

Comment: @Matthias It's not like i choose to use semicolons. But its there in OP's code and they are not in a way of solving his/her problem. So there is no reason for me to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

```
def newListEven (l):
    reverse_l=l[::-1]
    return [reverse_l[n]+ l[n] for n in range (0, int(len(l)/2))]
```

Comment: TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Thank you for informing, Fixed it.

Comment: @Prudhvi What keyword did OP used in his/her question?